# Open iCloud Pics in my app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, icloud, icloud-photo-library

I have to show all the iCloud picture in my app. So i have to use those photos for further actions.
Is there any framework which i have use to implement the iCloud functionality.
I have checked the various codes and tuts but not able to get the images form the iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Photos Framework to get access to photos on iCloud. Photos Framework also support photo editing.

For more details you can follow this link - [Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps what you are looking for is the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.

Make your class to inherit UIImagePickerControllerDelegate;

Create a function to pick image from library or camera, initialize a pickerController constant, set delegate to self, get pickerController source type, from camera or library, set allowsEditing to true and present view controller.

Check the code below:

```
class YourClass: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    ...

    @IBAction func picImage(sender: UIButton) {

            let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            pickerController.delegate = self
            pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            pickerController.allowsEditing = true

            self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            // before user finish picking image, another func has to run, imagePickerController.
        }

        // After user pick the image, this method will dismiss active view controller.
        func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

This is well understood when watching the link tutorial about CoreData, the video is a bit long but worth your time.
My thanks to Jason Rybka, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kCKlv1npw0.

Works for Swift 2.1 / iOS 9.2.

Good luck.